# Get parent class and trigger in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, jquery-selectors

I want to trigger an event of the parent class by clicking a button or image.

```
<li class="addImage">
<input class="PhotoPicker" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" />
<a class='imageclick' onclick=" $(this).closest('.PhotoPicker').trigger('click');">
    <img ng-src="images/add-photo.png">
</a>
```

Here `addImage` class is repeated and when I click on `imageclick` class, I want to trigger `photopicker` of that respective list. Its working good when I use,

```
('.PhotoPicker').trigger('click');
```

Kindly help me guys!

Comment: The method `closest()` searches for all matched parents of element, not siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not ancestors/descendants of each other.

You need to go up to the LI (nearest common ancestor) using `closest` then search down with `find`:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.PhotoPicker').trigger('click');
```

You can also shorten `trigger('click')` to just `.click()` as it does exactly the same thing behind the scenes:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.PhotoPicker').click();
```

You could use a sibling selector, but that is not as robust to changes being made in the DOM. Safer to use a common ancestor and find. For example, if the layout is changed for styling purposes and extra DIVs are added around elements, then sibling searches will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by sibling selectors not being as robust to changes in the DOM?

Comment: If the DOM changes (extra wrapping divs for formatting etc) sibling code will fail.

Comment: That's said, if OP is using angularjs, he shouldn't in first place using jQuery

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye Sorry for my bad grammar. I meant OP seems to use angularjs, `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"`, so i guess he shouldn't trying to fire event using any jQuery method. But i'm not a angular dev, so i'm just guessing...

Comment: @A.Wolff: Gotcha. Had not seen that until I scrolled it to the right. Yes, there may be issues combining angular events with jQuery, but I don't use Angular either.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye Ok i guess he just wants to open browser dialog file, so in fact nothing really wrong here

Comment: But It worked! thanks for the quick answer Gone Coding Goodbye

Comment: @ganesh to write this the angular way you'll want to make that `a` tag a directive. Put your DOM stuff in there.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I haven't down voted anything. Even tho the solution works I thought it would be helpful to know that this is not an angular best practice.

Comment: @Kilmazing: Please post your own `Angular`-based answer to show the correct best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Closest looks upwards at ancestors. You are wanting to go sideways to a sibling.

Can use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).prev().trigger('click');
```

Or

```
$(this).siblings('.PhotoPicker').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".imageclick").prev().trigger("click");
```

you can simply use a `prev` selector here..
https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 0):

You can move up the `DOM` to find its parents and then search for the required child

```
<li class="addImage">
    <input class="PhotoPicker" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" />
    <a class='imageclick' onclick="someFunction()">
        <img ng-src="images/add-photo.png">
    </a>
```

JS

```
 function(){
         $(this).parent().find('.PhotoPicker').trigger('click');
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/90597hzy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the use of `closest` , it's job is to go upwards through its parent elements, NOT SIBLINGS, in your markup the class `PhotoPicker` is a sibling element, not a parent/ancestor element.

But `addImage` is a parent/ancestor element to `imageclick`. So you can access this using `closest` like this;

```
$(this).closest('.addImage')
```

and then you can use the `find` function to get the `PhotoPicker` element inside it like:

```
$(this).closest('.addImage').find('.PhotoPicker').first().trigger('click')
```